# Invalid block XX: unknown ancestor while restoring the chain - private blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, geth-clique

I'm trying to restore blockchain using import a rlp file

```
geth import backup.rlp
```

It show an error

[image]

Is there any way to exclude the bad blocks while exporting the chain data?

Also, if the `gcmode` is `archive` then only can get past data of smart contract state?

Geth version: 1.8.16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the image, it seems to me you are importing the backup of a private network to a node initializated with the Mainnet.

I suspect this because:

- geth says ChainID is 1, so Mainnet
- the import process seems to stop with the very first block and
  the error is *unknown ancestor*, so it don't know the genesis block
- your block #1 hash is not the hash of the first block of the Mainnet, that is 0x88e96d4537bea4d9c05d12549907b32561d3bf31f45aae734cdc119f13406cb6

If this is the case, just remove the geth database:

```
$ geth removedb
```

and init again with the correct genesis block:

```
$ geth --networkid [yourNetworkID] init [yourGenesisFile.json]
```

If you don't remember the networkID, you should be able to read it in the genesis file.

Comment: This worked, thanks a lot! the only change is _the flags need to come after geth and before init_ as stated [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/3236#issuecomment-258834151)

Comment: Unfortunately bounty has ended :(

Comment: No problem for the bounty, if I can I respond to questions in any case :) I fixed the syntax as you reported.

Comment: Hey, I have some further questions. [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/86965/39618), [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/86992/39618), [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/86915/39618) and [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/86996/39618) Would be great if you can help there.