# Served eth_sendTransaction err="unknown account"

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, accounts

I'm facing issue with private chain, when I run the node, it shows the logs as below, and transaction went in pending status.

[image]

Folder structure

[image]

All the wallet file reside into keystore folder.

Node.sh file

```
GLOBAL_ARGS="--nodiscover --gasprice 0 --targetgaslimit 470000000000 --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcapi admin,db,eth,debug,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3 --mine --minerthreads 1"
echo "Starting node 1.....!"

nohup /usr/bin/geth --port 30304 --datadir=/node1 $GLOBAL_ARGS --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain "*" --allow-insecure-unlock --unlock "address" --password password.txt &
```

Geth
Version: 1.9.14-stable

**Edit-1**
Here is the code I'm using to send transactions.

```
const newAccount =  await provider.web3.personal.newAccount(request.wallet_password);        
if (newAccount != null) {

    await provider.web3.eth.sendTransaction({
        from: provider.web3.eth.coinbase,
        to: newAccount,
        value: provider.web3.toWei(1, "ether")
    });
}
```

Comment: How was the account created ? Can you see your address when doing "eth.accounts" ?

Comment: Accounts created using web3js, yes it shows all the addresses on `eth.accounts` @clement

Comment: Ok, can you show the part of your code responsible for sending the transaction ?

Comment: Sure, I have added the code in the question @clement