# Why my private chain starting Geth on Ethereum mainnet

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, geth-clique

My private ethereum showing log "starting Geth on Ethereum mainnet.."
here are the full logs

```
INFO [08-27|09:14:02.302] Starting Geth on Ethereum mainnet... 
INFO [08-27|09:14:02.302] Bumping default cache on mainnet         provided=1024 updated=4096
WARN [08-27|09:14:02.302] Sanitizing cache to Go's GC limits       provided=4096 updated=2645
INFO [08-27|09:14:02.305] Maximum peer count                       ETH=50 LES=0 total=50
WARN [08-27|09:14:02.305] The flag --rpc is deprecated and will be removed in the future, please use --http 
WARN [08-27|09:14:02.305] The flag --rpcaddr is deprecated and will be removed in the future, please use --http.addr 
WARN [08-27|09:14:02.305] The flag --rpcport is deprecated and will be removed in the future, please use --http.port 
WARN [08-27|09:14:02.305] The flag --rpccorsdomain is deprecated and will be removed in the future, please use --http.corsdomain 
WARN [08-27|09:14:02.305] The flag --rpcapi is deprecated and will be removed in the future, please use --http.api 
INFO [08-27|09:14:02.305] Smartcard socket not found, disabling    err="stat /run/pcscd/pcscd.comm: no such file or directory"
ERROR[08-27|09:14:02.306] Failed to enumerate USB devices          hub=ledger vendor=11415 failcount=1 err="failed to initialize libusb: libusb: unknown error [code -99]"
ERROR[08-27|09:14:02.306] Failed to enumerate USB devices          hub=trezor vendor=21324 failcount=1 err="failed to initialize libusb: libusb: unknown error [code -99]"
ERROR[08-27|09:14:02.306] Failed to enumerate USB devices          hub=trezor vendor=4617  failcount=1 err="failed to initialize libusb: libusb: unknown error [code -99]"
ERROR[08-27|09:14:02.306] Failed to enumerate USB devices          hub=ledger vendor=11415 failcount=2 err="failed to initialize libusb: libusb: unknown error [code -99]"
ERROR[08-27|09:14:02.306] Failed to enumerate USB devices          hub=trezor vendor=21324 failcount=2 err="failed to initialize libusb: libusb: unknown error [code -99]"
ERROR[08-27|09:14:02.306] Failed to enumerate USB devices          hub=trezor vendor=4617  failcount=2 err="failed to initialize libusb: libusb: unknown error [code -99]"
WARN [08-27|09:14:02.307] The flag --targetgaslimit is deprecated and will be removed in the future, please use --miner.gastarget 
WARN [08-27|09:14:02.307] The flag --gasprice is deprecated and will be removed in the future, please use --miner.gasprice 
INFO [08-27|09:14:02.307] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/ _node_1/v1.9.14-stable-6d74d1e5/linux-amd64/go1.14.2
INFO [08-27|09:14:02.307] Allocated trie memory caches             clean=396.00MiB dirty=661.00MiB
INFO [08-27|09:14:02.307] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/blockchain3/node2/geth/chaindata cache=1.29GiB handles=524288
INFO [08-27|09:14:02.350] Opened ancient database                  database=/home/blockchain3/node2/geth/chaindata/ancient
INFO [08-27|09:14:02.350] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 1919 Homestead: 0 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: false EIP150: 0 EIP155: 0 EIP158: 0 Byzantium: 0 Constantinople: 0 Petersburg: 0 Istanbul: 0, Muir Glacier: <nil>, Engine: clique}"
INFO [08-27|09:14:02.351] Initialising Ethereum protocol           versions="[65 64 63]" network=1 dbversion=7
INFO [08-27|09:14:02.352] Loaded most recent local header          number=3 hash="c16c84â€¦0380b2" td=7 age=1w21h6m
INFO [08-27|09:14:02.352] Loaded most recent local full block      number=1 hash="c489b9â€¦4d9893" td=3 age=1mo2w6d
INFO [08-27|09:14:02.352] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=3 hash="c16c84â€¦0380b2" td=7 age=1w21h6m
INFO [08-27|09:14:02.354] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0
WARN [08-27|09:14:02.354] Switch sync mode from fast sync to full sync 
INFO [08-27|09:14:02.385] New local node record                    seq=11 id=29b23ef718418689 ip=127.0.0.1 udp=0 tcp=30305
INFO [08-27|09:14:02.385] Started P2P networking                   self="enode://enodeaddress@127.0.0.1:30305?discport=0"
INFO [08-27|09:14:02.385] IPC endpoint opened                      url=/home/blockchain3/node2/geth.ipc
ERROR[08-27|09:14:02.385] Unavailable modules in HTTP API list     unavailable="[db shh]" available="[admin debug web3 eth txpool personal clique miner net]"
INFO [08-27|09:14:02.386] HTTP endpoint opened                     url=http://[::]:8546/                       cors=* vhosts=localhost
ERROR[08-27|09:14:03.318] Failed to enumerate USB devices          hub=trezor vendor=4617  failcount=3 err="failed to initialize libusb: libusb: unknown error [code -99]"
ERROR[08-27|09:14:03.318] Failed to enumerate USB devices          hub=trezor vendor=21324 failcount=3 err="failed to initialize libusb: libusb: unknown error [code -99]"
ERROR[08-27|09:14:03.318] Failed to enumerate USB devices          hub=ledger vendor=11415 failcount=3 err="failed to initialize libusb: libusb: unknown error [code -99]"
INFO [08-27|09:14:03.562] Unlocked account                         address= 0x903xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx6022917d
INFO [08-27|09:14:03.562] Transaction pool price threshold updated price=80000000000
WARN [08-27|09:14:03.562] The flag --minerthreads is deprecated and will be removed in the future, please use --miner.threads 
INFO [08-27|09:14:03.562] Transaction pool price threshold updated price=80000000000
INFO [08-27|09:14:03.562] Etherbase automatically configured       address= 0x903xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx6022917d
INFO [08-27|09:14:03.563] Commit new mining work                   number=2 sealhash="4e5f7dâ€¦34e750" uncles=0 txs=0 gas=0 fees=0 elapsed="154.706Âµs"
INFO [08-27|09:14:03.563] Sealing paused, waiting for transactions 
INFO [08-27|09:14:58.538] Setting new local account                address= 0x903xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx6022917d
INFO [08-27|09:14:58.538] Submitted transaction                    fullhash=0x55d8b4744a094860a8d65427e117843e1b595261b49b8772bdef930e37276b0a recipient=0x0c2dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxE2E280
```

Script of node

```
GLOBAL_ARGS="--nodiscover --gasprice 0 --targetgaslimit 470000000000 --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcapi admin,db,eth,debug,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3  --mine --minerthreads 2"
echo "Starting node.....!"

nohup /usr/bin/geth --port 30305 --datadir=$pwd  $GLOBAL_ARGS --rpcport 8546 --rpccorsdomain "*" --identity "node_1" --allow-insecure-unlock --unlock "0x903xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx6022917d" --password pwd.txt &

echo "Node started successfully"
```

Genesis File

```
{
  "config": {
    "chainId": 1919,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip150Block": 0,
    "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0,
    "byzantiumBlock": 0,
    "constantinopleBlock": 0,
    "petersburgBlock": 0,
    "istanbulBlock": 0,
    "clique": {
      "period": 0,
      "epoch": 30000
    }
  },
  "nonce": "0x0",
  "timestamp": "0x5f04700a",
  "extraData": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000447c4bcd61d828b13e084724dcd21ef00",
  "gasLimit": "0x82f79cd9000",
  "difficulty": "0x1",
  "mixHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
```

When connecting node

```
> admin.nodeInfo
```

---

```
protocols: {
eth: {
  config: {
    byzantiumBlock: 0,
    chainId: 1919,
    clique: {...},
    constantinopleBlock: 0,
    eip150Block: 0,
    eip150Hash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    eip155Block: 0,
    eip158Block: 0,
    homesteadBlock: 0,
    istanbulBlock: 0,
    petersburgBlock: 0
  },
  difficulty: 3,
  genesis: "0xa8a906a1f2f9ea21567b95234299803228d7c2d981dfa145cea9bd5a745df5f6",
  head: "0xc489b9bfc546923bb515e64cfba83f86fa32128871d57c6f1917a98d7f4d9893",
  network: 1
}
```

Geth information

```
Geth
Version: 1.9.14-stable
Git Commit: 6d74d1e5f762e06a6a739a42261886510f842778
Architecture: amd64
Protocol Versions: [65 64 63]
Go Version: go1.14.2
Operating System: linux
GOPATH=
GOROOT=/build/ethereum-hL1NP5/.go
```

Comment: How are you sure it mining the Mainnnet? This looks like a dev chain to me

Comment: When I start the node, the it shows `INFO Starting Geth on Ethereum mainnet...`. I have also found `ethash` folder generated on the machine, I have deleted it and now it's not being generated @SamuelDare

Comment: nodeInfo output chainId 1919, on logs it's reported the same (Initialised chain configuration line),  try to clean all folders and do init again, seems all corrects.

Comment: @Dibi91 The issue is, my chain was running fine, there was a space issue, I have checked and found ethash folder consuming 29GB, searched online, and found safe to delete that file. Deleted and start node again...it shows block-height 1 and all transaction goes into pending. I can't my previous blocks and data...

Comment: Sorry, did not read carefully the starting command, see the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You should add at the starting command the `networkid` flag.

From the geth help command:

```
--networkid value    Network identifier (integer, 1=Frontier, 3=Ropsten, 4=Rinkeby, 5=Görli) (default: 1)
```

So without value, it get 1 as default and goes on mainnet